# google cloud functions "Maximum function instances" regularly exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed a pubsub function on GCP with the command line switch `--max-instances 20` and I can see on the front end that value is correct "Maximum function instance" reads "20".

When I look at the metrics explorer, and filter by "Resource Type: cloud function" and "Metric: Active Instances", it shows that up to 92 instance are running.  It's a big problem for me because these connect to a cloud-sql postgresql db, which rapidly runs out of connections and my application grinds to a halt.

Is this a known problem?  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce your issue, but the amount of instances is 1 for a test function with a bit more than 20 requests.

I recommend you to directly file a case through the [Google Cloud Platform Support portal](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub).